# Redux: altering different parts of the initial state in Reducer according to Actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I have the following Reducer:

```
const initialState = {}

const dishReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LOAD_DISHES': 
        return (action.dishes)
    
      case 'LOAD_DISHES_ERROR': 
        console.log("load dishes error")
        return state
      case 'LOAD_DISHES_SUCCESS': 
        console.log("load dishes success")
        return state
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  export default dishReducer;
```

And the following action(s):

```
import {database} from '../../config/fbConfig'

export const startLoadingDishes = (dishes) => {
    return (dispatch) =>{
        return database.ref('products-dishes').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            let dishes = {}
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                let parentkey = childSnapshot.key
                let dishArray = [];
                childSnapshot.forEach((dish) =>{
                        dishArray.push(dish.val())
                    });
                dishes[childSnapshot.key] = dishArray;
            })
    
            dispatch(loadDishes(dishes))
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DISHES_SUCCESS' });
          }).catch(err => {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DISHES_ERROR' }, err);
          });
    }

}

export const loadDishes = (dishes) => { 
    return {
        type: 'LOAD_DISHES',
        dishes               
    }
}
```

The 'startLoadingDishes' action is called inside the componentDidLoad() of a certain Component. However, I want to alter the initial state of my dishReducer so that it includes additional information, as follows:

```
const initialState = {
    value : {},
    loaded: false,
    loading: false,
    error: false
}
```

So now 'action.dishes' returned by reducer [in 'LOAD_DISHES' case] should be put inside the 'value' part of the state, instead of it being the whole state. Also, the 'loaded' part of the state should be set to true if dishes have already been loaded earlier, and so on. I understand this is fairly simple but as I am new to React+Redux, I don't know how to alter the Action/Reducer codes properly (while keeping state immutability). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally asked the question, here is how I solved it (not sure if this is the 'best' way though):

New reducer file:

```
const initialState = {
    value : {},
    loaded: false,
    loading: false,
    error: false
}

const dishReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LOAD_DISHES': 
        return {
          value: action.dishes,
          loading: !state.loading,
          loaded: false,   //this might need to be set to true
          error: false
        }
    
      case 'LOAD_DISHES_ERROR': 
        console.log("load dishes error")
        return {
          ...state,   //or: state.value, as the other parts of state are being overwritten below
          loaded: false,
          loading: false,
          error: true
        }
      case 'LOAD_DISHES_SUCCESS': 
        console.log("load dishes success")
        return { 
          ...state,  //better: state.value
          loaded: true,
          loading: false,
          error: false
        }
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  export default dishReducer;
```

No change in actions file.

Now, inside the 'Main' component, I was originally accessing the state as such:

```
class Main extends Component {

  componentDidMount() { 
    this.props.startLoadingDishes();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      //some code
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    dishes: state.dishes  //to access dishes: dishes.value
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Main)
```

The Main component code also stayed the same, with the difference that now I use 'dishes.value' instead of just 'dishes' to access the value of dishes from the state (and dishes.loaded for loaded, and so on). And now the action caller inside componentDidMount is as follows:

```
componentDidMount() { 
    if(!this.props.dishes.loaded){
      this.props.startLoadingDishes();
      console.log("loading dishes from database")
    }
  }
```